# Term for composition of all three of position, velocity, and acceleration?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a (preferably technical) term that means “the position, velocity, and acceleration” of an object? It would be a nice addition if there were also a distinct word that includes [*jerk*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerk_(physics)).

I was thinking about *dynamics* or *kinetics*, but that often seems to imply force and mass. *Movement properties* might be ok, but it needs to be clearly defined before using it.

This question is inspired by the clarity that [*pose*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pose_(computing)) (the combination of position and orientation) provides.

#### Example usage:

> The end effector’s ________ was beyond its safe limits.

Comment: How about [vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector)?

Comment: I don't recognise the word 'jerk' in this context and cannot find a definition that seems to fit. Is it what I know in UK usage as 'impulse'?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerk_(physics)

Answer (score 4):

You are correct that "dynamics" and "kinetics" don't really work for what you want, but "kinematics" does. [From M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/kinematics):

> : a branch of dynamics that deals with aspects of motion apart from considerations of mass and force

(You're probably aware that velocity, acceleration, and jerk are simply derivatives of position with respect to time. I don't know of any succinct term to describe that, though.)

Comment: First, second, and third derivatives, respectively.

Comment: @JohnLawler Yes, but this question is tagged as a SWR, so I don't think that phrase would work.

Answer (score 1):

The closest established terms would be tool path, trajectory, and trace. All involve the history of motion of the end effector, as opposed to an instantaneous reading of the dynamic values. The tool path can often be effected in multiple ways, so you are really saying that no control vector can safely map the desired trajectory.

As used in control theory, a trajectory is precisely the inverse of what you want. It is a series of time-ordered positions from which you can derive the instantaneous velocity and acceleration at any point on the trajectory. Since the information you want can be extracted from a trajectory, that's the word I would use, *mutatis mutandis*. But I really want to know if the constraint that was exceeded was external (crashed into a wall) or internal (actuator slew rate exceeded).

The (desired) end effector's trajectory exceeded the [manipulability](https://modernrobotics.northwestern.edu/nu-gm-book-resource/5-4-manipulability/) limits.